# Firebase database transactional search and update

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, transactions

I have a collection in firebase real time database that is a pool of codes that can be used once per 'store'. I need to search for an unused code, then mark it reserved by a store in an atomic fashion. The problem is I can't figure out how to do a transactional search and update in firebase, and the unused code is being 'used' multiple times until it gets updated.

```
const getUnusedCode = (storeID) => {
  const codeRef = rtdb.ref('codes');

 return codeRef
    .orderByChild(storeID)
    .equalTo(null)
    .limitToFirst(1)
    .once('child_added')
    .then(snap => {
     //setting the map {[storeID]:true} reserves the code
     return snap.ref.update({ [storeID]: true }).then(() => {
        return snap.key;
      });
    });
};
```

Edit: Here is the structure of the 'codes' collection:

```
{
  "-LQl9FFD39PAeN5DnrGE" : {
    "code" : 689343821901,
    "i" : 0,
    "5s6EgdItKW7pBIawgulg":true,
    "ZK0lFbDnXcWJ6Gblg0tV":true,
    "uKbwxPbZu2fJlsn998vm":true
  },
  "-LQl9FOxT4eq6EbwrwOx" : {
    "code" : 689343821918,
    "i" : 1,
    "5s6EgdItKW7pBIawgulg":true
  },
  "-LQl9FPaUV33fvkiFtv-" : {
    "code" : 689343821925,
    "i" : 2
  },
  "-LQl9FQEwKKO9T0z4LIP" : {
    "code" : 689343821932,
    "i" : 3,
    "ZK0lFbDnXcWJ6Gblg0tV":true
  },
  "-LQl9FQsEVSNZyhgdHmI" : {
    "code" : 689343821949,
    "i" : 4,
    "5s6EgdItKW7pBIawgulg":true,
    "uKbwxPbZu2fJlsn998vm":true
  }
}
```

In this data, "5s6EgdItKW7pBIawgulg" is a store id, and true means this code has been used for this store

When new items are being imported, this function may get called hundres of times a minute, and is returning duplicates since it's not an atomic search-then-update. Is this possible in Firebase?

Comment: This indeed requires a [Firebase database transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions). If you're having trouble making it work, can you add the JSON structure that this code is querying (as text, no screenshot please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). It also would be nice to see what you've already tried with a transaction.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you for the response! I edited the question to include the current structure. Also, it may be good to know that I only chose rtdb because of assumed performance increases over firestore. only this code collection is in rtbd, the rest of my data is in firestore, so if the simple answer is 'move it to Firestore for betetr transactions', I'm good with that. Also, the structure is flexible  as well.

Comment: Technology recommendations are off-topic. But if you've used Firestore for everything else, I'd use it for this feature too. [Premature optimization](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization) being what it is and all.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you have a structure like this

```
codes: {
  "code1": {
    storeid: "store1"
  },
  "code2": {
    storeid: "store2"
  }
}
```

And you're trying to transactionally update it per store.

If this is the only update you're trying to do, I'd highly recommend inverting your data structure:

```
codes: {
  "store1": "code1",
  "store2": "code2"
}
```

On this structure the transaction for a store is quite simple, since the path is known:

```
var storeRef = firebase.database().ref("codes").child("store1");
storeRef.transation(function(current) {
  if (current) {
    // remove the code from the database
    return null;
  }
  else {
    // abort the transaction, since the code no longer exists
    return undefined;
  }
});
```

If you can't change the data structure, I'd probably user your current code to find the `DatabaseReference` to the code, and then use a transaction within the callback to update:

```
codeRef
    .orderByChild(storeID)
    .equalTo(null)
    .limitToFirst(1)
    .once('child_added')
    .then(snap => {
      //setting the map {[storeID]:true} reserves the code
      return snap.ref.transaction(function(current) {
        if (!current || current[storeId]) {
          // the node no longer exists, or it already was claimed for this store
          return undefined; // abort the transaction
        }
        else {
          current[storeId] = true;
          return current;
        }
      })
    });
```

Comment: My last code sample assumes your current query finds the right node. If it doesn't: do you know the code that is being claimed?

Comment: each time a 'store' imports a new record, it needs to find an unused code and claim it by writing the store_id to that code's record. I don't know the code ahead of time, which is why i'm getting all the duplicates - each import is searching and getting the same unused code until one of the writes that claims the code succeeds. I think if the read fails along with the write because it's wrapped in a transaction, that may work

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but still get duplicates on the query portion of the function. If I call 'getUnusedCode(storeId)' in a loop, It still returns duplicates since the query runs asynchronously before the transaction ever runs, it fetches the same first query result 12 or so times before the transaction ever writes the storeId to the code, marking it used. I'm not actually sure my problem ('find and reserve the first available code') can be solved with firebase real time database transactions. Since firestore transactions also include get() operations, that may be by only option

Comment: In my second sample the transaction is *inside* the callback, so will only run once the query has executed.

Comment: I ended up migrating the codes data to a firestore collection and wrapping the query and update in a transaction and it works, but the performance is terrible since there is still contention when a search/update is done. I just depend on the internal transaction retry to work. If I'm searching for an unused code (storeId == null) from 4 import tasks each trying to fetch an unused code about 1/sec, I get tremendous data contention. I'm not blaming Firestore, I'm just not sure of the correct way to do high performance transactional search-then-updates.

Comment: Contention on a high traffic node/document/collection is always a limit on scalability. Try to reframe your operation into an append-only type write. E.g. instead of storing a balance that everyone updates, store transactions that a server (or Cloud Functions) then periodically updates. But I'm still not sure why my approach doesn't work for you.