# firebase RTDB transactional delete

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been using firestore transactions quite well and have been trying to implement some RTDB versions.

I have a tree with autogenerated keys. The values of these keys are maps, whereby one of the keys is 'uid' e.g.

```
"AUTOGENKEY" : {
    "uid" : 'a uid'
}, 
...etc
```

I want to have a transaction where i can delete all of a singles users nodes... if any new nodes are created by the user during the transaction it should retry and include the new nodes in the transaction delete.

I currently have this

```
await rtdb.ref(‘someRef’)
    .orderByChild(‘uid’)
    .equalTo(uid)
    .once('value')
    .transaction(function(currentVal) {
            // Loop each of the nodes with a matching ‘uid’ and delete them
            // If any of the nodes are updated (or additional nodes are created with matching uids)
           // while the transaction is running it should restart and retry the delete        
           // If no nodes are matched nothing should happen    
    });
```

But I wanted to double check whether i need another transaction inside the currentVal callback and whether or not i can just return null to delete each of the nodes.

I have been using this answer as a reference [Firebase database transactional search and update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53568052/firebase-database-transactional-search-and-update)

Kind regards

-Edit for new method

I have taken your advide frank and have ended up just storing my data like so:

```
uid -> counter
```

I didn't know transactions didnt cannot run on queries, thanks for letting me know.

I need to be able to add/subtract quantities from the uids count and if it ever results in a number below 0 the node should be deleted. If i pass null as an amount it should delete the node. This is what i currently have.

```
async function incrementOrDecrementByAmount(pathToUid, shouldAdd, amount, rtdb){

  await rtdb.ref(pathToUid)
    .transaction(function(currentVal) {
   
      if(currentVal == null || amount == null) {
        return amount;
      }else{
        let newAmount = null;

        // Just sum the new amount
        if(shouldAdd == true) {
          newAmount = currentVal + amount;
        } else {
          const diff = currentVal - amount;

          // If its not above 0 then leave it null so it is deleted
          if(newAmount > 0) {
            newAmount = diff;
          }
        }

        return newAmount;
      }
    });
}
```

I am not sure about the first if statement, if I have the following execution.

1. incrementOrDecrementByAmount(somePath, 10, true, rtdb)
2. incrementOrDecrementByAmount(somePath, 100, false, rtdb)

Will this always result in the node being deleted? are the transaction always dependent on the call order or is it a race condition on who finishes first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A transaction can only be run on a `DatabaseReference`, not on a `Query`. So in your case, you will have to run a transaction on the complete `someRef` node, and then modify the `currentVal` to remove the nodes where the `uid` property matches your condition.

If there are many `uid` values this may lead to reading significantly more data than needed, and if multiple users may performing this operation at the same time this may lead to contention and retries. In such cases, consider an alternative data structure, that allows you to run a more isolated transaction, for example by storing the nodes for each `uid` value under that value as a key.

```
someRef: {
  "uid1": {
    ...
  },
  "uid2": {
    ...
  }
}
```

With such a structure, removing all values for a single `uid` can be performed with a simple, single write operation.

Comment: Hi Frank. Thanks for the feedback. I have changed my db structure and have written a new method. Could you please check if I have done the transaction correctly

Comment: You'll need to move the `return newAmount` two lines up, into the previous `}`. But aside from that it looks good at first glance. Note: I'd personally merge the `shouldAdd, amount` parameters, and just pass a positive or negative amount into the function.

Comment: Sure ill accept your answer! I left the line at the bottom because of the reason in the  comment ```// If its not above 0 then leave it null so it is deleted ```... Thanks for the help!